# Unable to catch Exception of suspendCoroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So,

I have a function that has a callback so I wrapped it up in a suspend function using `suspendCoroutine` but when it errors out it is crashing the entire app.

For a piece of concept here is what is happening.

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

scope.launch {
    try {
        test()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
         logE { e.asLog() }
    }
}

suspend fun test() = suspendCoroutine<Unit> { cont ->
     cont.resumeWithException(IllegalStateException("Umm")) // The andoird app is crashing 
}
```

> 2022-03-04 16:09:45.410 19289-19438/in.app.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
> Process: in.app.android, PID: 19289
> java.lang.Throwable: Umm
> at in.app.android.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.kt:187)
> at in.app.android.MainActivity$onCreate$5.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:177)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)

How can I catch any exception when getting throws in the `suspendCoroutine` clause?

**EDIT**

SO, the problem was I was throwing a Throwable but catching an exception.

Comment: can you provide the proper context of what you are trying to do, here the code looks normal and does not seem like it would crash anything.

Comment: @rahat check, also if can try it in your code too

Comment: Your problem is in another place, really. You can't catch exception of the code running inside `launch()`, because it is asynchronous. You would need to put `try` inside `launch {}`. This is totally unrelated to callbacks and `suspendCoroutine()`.

Comment: Also, you catch `Exception`, but throw `Throwable`. First is a subtype of the latter.

Comment: @broot it's also happening when putting try-catch inside the launch.

Comment: DId you read my last comment? Your question is misleading right now, because it shows that you throw `Exception`, but logs clearly show you actually throw `Throwable`. I assume you don't really use this above code, but still your original one, before the edit. If so then well, `Throwable` is not `Exception`! This is why it is not being caught.

Comment: @broot oh yeah! It fixed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As broot mentioned, your log shows that your someService is throwing a Throwable not an Exception.
You will be fine if you change your code like this

```
try {
     test()
} catch (e: Throwable) {
      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try **suspendCancellableCoroutine** ? You can invoke the callback on **invokeOnCancellation** end of callback method like below :

```
cont.invokeOnCancellation {
            callback = null
        }
```

for implementation, make the local variable of your callback and check the **CancellableContinuation** isActive as following

```
 fun onFail(e: Exception) {
     if (cont.isActive) {
        cont.resumeWithException(e)
     }
 }
```